# Is it possible to get the minimum ascent of all characters in font via fontconfig or pango?

Tags: linux, fontconfig, pangocairo

I can see in pango that we can query the maximum ascent (i.e. vertical distance from the horizontal baseline to the highest ‘character’ coordinate).

But I also need the minimum ascent. Is this possible via pango/fontconfig or some other library? (linux)

Comment: There is no need for such a function, mainly because "ascent" is not a fixed value: every character in a font may have a different ascent. The "max" is just provided for very basic accent placement. (You should not, for instance, try to use it to determine line heights.)

Comment: @Jongware - I have to provide this value for someone else - what they use the minimum ascent for is beyond my control.

Comment: Then you have to ask them. Since "ascent" is just the highest point of the font overall ( it's not defined if this should include or exclude any accents), "the" minimum could be the height of a full stop `.`; or even *negative*, since an underscore `_` usually lives *below* the baseline.

Comment: ok yes fair comment. i've since realised, that actually they don't mean minimum ascent. they actually mean descent. which, when added to ascent, they can use to calculate line height.